# socket.error [Errno 19] no such device - Scapy Python

Tags: python, scapy

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "wifi_founder.py", line 9, in <module>
   sniff(iface="mon0", prn=PacketHandler)                
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 561, in sniff                
   s = L2socket(type=ETH_P_ALL, *arg, **karg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 455, in __init__
   self.ins.bind((iface, type))
File "/home/etai/PycharmProjects/wifi_founder/socket.py", line 228, in meth
   return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 19] No such device
```

when i was trying to debug this code using scapy,i got the error above, i simply don't no what to for resolving it. the code was written in python:

```
from scapy.all import *
ap_list = []
def PacketHandler(pkt):
   if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
      if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8:
          if pkt.addr2 not in ap_list:
             ap_list.append(pkt.addr2)
             print "AP MAC: %s with SSID: %s" % (pkt.addr2, pkt.info)
sniff(iface="mon0", prn=PacketHandler)
```

Comment: It seems like your computer doesn't hold a network interface named `mon0`. What network interfaces are defined in your computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use 'mon0', you may consider using:

```
sniff(iface=conf.iface, prn=PacketHandler)
```

Instead, as it will auto-select the best interface (the default one)